# Symfony 2: Prevent header display in xml response

Tags: php, xml, symfony

So I'm trying to create a xml document with symfony. The generation works without issues and I return the document with a twig templates named `sitemap.xml.twig` in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    {% for slug in slugArray %}
    <url>
        <loc>{{ slug }}</loc>
        <lastmod>{{ curDate }}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    {% endfor %}
</urlset>
```

In the controller, I call the template with:

```
    $response = new Response($this->render(
        'MyBundle:Sitemap:sitemap.xml.twig',
        [
            'slugArray' => $slugArray,
            'curDate' => $curDate
        ]
    ));

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');

    return $response;
```

`$slugArray` contains around 1000 links which are all valid, while `$curDate` contains the value of `date('Y-m-d', time())`.

However, when I try to to access the sitemap, I get the following error:

```
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: nicht wohlgeformt
Adresse: http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/sitemap.xml
Zeile Nr. 1, Spalte 5:

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
----^
```

This is basically meaning the xml document is not well formed.

So for some reason, the header is taken into account when parsing the xml, creating an error. The xml itself is completely valid, when I copy the response from the dev tools in firefox, leave the header and check them with online validators, I get no error.

When I remove the `$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');`, I get plain HTML.

So how can I create an xml response which can be parsed by a browser without issues?

Comment: Have you tried loading the response directly in Chrome, with different charsets? I remember that I came across similar problems when I created API endpoints with Symfony, but it was after all only the issue of the browser at that time.

Comment: have you tried setting things individually on the response? E.g `$response = new Response();
$response->setContent($this->render('MyBundle:Sitemap:sitemap.xml.twig',['slugArray' => $slugArray,'curDate' => $curDate]));
$response->setCharset('charset=utf-8');
$response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
$response->send();`

Comment: @Rooneyl I did, but it didn't affect the outcome at all

Comment: @ScalatronMotoroller I tried, but chrome says the page is empty, even tho when i check the source code, it is not

Answer (score 0):

if you use twig to generate xml content, in your controller you already get a response.
in your controller :

```
$response = $this->render('....:sitemap.xml.twig', array('urls'=>$urls));
// at this stage $xml is an HttpFoudation Response Object;
// simply set de content type
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'xml');
$response->setCharset('utf-8');
return $response;
```